# ubuntu shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity’s keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Where can I see a list of ubuntu shortcuts/hotkeys ?

The kinds of things I would like to do are like (using Windows) :
WinKey + R = Run command
WinKey + T = focus on the task bar
Ctrl + Shift + N = create a new folder
Alt + D = focus on the address of the windows/file explorer

Thanks