# Is there a way to extend Unity's window placement shortcuts?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

In Unity there is the way of using `Ctrl+Super+(left|right)` to extend the current window eighter on left or right side.

Is there any way to extend this so you can place it in top_left an bottom_left ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Window Placement

If you cycle through the same key Unity will cycle through different placement widths, so experiment by hitting the numkey multiple times, for example Ctrl-Alt-numpad 5 5 5:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> - Place window in top left corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> - Place window in top half of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> - Place window in top right corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> - Center/Maximize the window in the middle of the screen. In 12.04 this toggles between maximize and restore state
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> - Place window in the bottom left corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> - Place window in the bottom half of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> - Place window in the bottom right corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> - Minimize the current window (Ubuntu 12.04.1).

---

Source: [Unity's Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/28087/114818)