# keyboard shortcut for multiple monitors

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, focus

Is there a keyboard shortcut for switching focus from one monitor to the next in Unity?

Basically, if I am working on my web-browser on my right screen, how can I switch to my terminal on my left screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have terminal on your right screen, too, you can simply <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to terminal and focus will move accordingly.

That said, you might want to check out [this related post on Ubuntu shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).