# Applications using shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

is possible to find out if any application uses some short-cut? I would like to assign some action to short-cut but don't know if its already used. Thank You

Comment: What application are you talking about?  What action do you want to assign to what app?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this previous thread, it has a list of the shortcuts.

[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/28087#28087)

http://allhotkeys.com/ubuntu_hotkeys.html

The above is a link to a couple of different short-cuts in use also