# Custom keyboard shortcut not working in Saucy

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, shortcuts

I'm trying to set up a shortcut that will open the gnome-control-center to the display tab.

The command for this is `gnome-control-center display` which works in a terminal and in the dash.

I set up the custom keyboard shortcut in the `settings > keyboard > shortcuts` panel but no matter what I set as the shortcut, nothing happens. In the command, I tried to echo text into a file but nothing happens either.

How should I set up my custom keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Logging out and back in helps. However, I changed the shortcut for "Toggle maximize" and the default shortcut is set back after a logout/reboot. I am still puzzled.

Comment: I began having this problem several months ago when I was still using Ubuntu 13.04. Probably next thing to do is to check if this a GNOME bug, e.g. by testing it in a non-Ubuntu Gnome desktop.

Comment: I also checked `dconf-editor`. I had two custom keyboard shortcuts under `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybindings` listed as "Custom0" (Ctrl+Alt+Del=SystemMonitor) and "Custom1" (Ctrl+g=MyScript). Both 2 used to work until late 2013. System Monitor still works! But the second one doesn't, and if I add a third command with a custom keyboard shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+g=gedit), it doesn't work either... Interesting puzzle...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1224732

It has only recently affected me. I was fine on 13.10, but some recent updates have killed my shortcuts.

They work fine in a gnome session, but do nothing in ubuntu. I'm not knowledgeable enough with the workings of this area to debug it though :/

Answer (score 0):

After many many tests, I've discovered that **the first thing to test** is whether the command or script concerned **really works** (e.g. using command line) or not, and then **the second thing to test** is whether **the custom key combination** chosen (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+D) conflicts with another one in use.

Unfortunately, the second problem seems much more difficult to resolve because the current gnome-control-center system apparently does/can not warn all such conflicts.

For instance, in the case mentioned here (`gnome-control-center display`) a custom keyboard shortcut such as Ctrl+Alt+D doesn't work - without any warning when assigning it - but a custom keyboard shortcut such as **Ctrl+Super+Backspace** does work.

Therefore, one might need a lot of trial-and-error work to find a **good** keyboard shortcut.

***Notes:***

1. It might also be necessary to **log out and then log back in** for the newly assigned keyboard shortcut to work.
2. In addition to many keyboard shortcuts used in various application, here are some **Unity keyboard shortcuts** to avoid: [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)