# Gnome3 Win+M in Unity (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys

Is there a shortcut in Unity (Ubuntu 12.04) for showing the open windows for the current desktop similar to what in Gnome 3 is achievable by "Win+M" shortcut (the image below is an example of this)?

[image]

EDIT: Long "Super" button pressure revealed a graphical list of the avaialable shortcuts, and I realized that what in Gnome3 is "Super+M", in my version of Unity is "Super+W".

The only thing I'm missing in Unity from Gnome3 is to be able to place the windows in a different workspace from that screen (as you can see, in the rightmost part you have got the workspaces in Gnome3), but I'm doing this from "Super+S" screen. It is a bit more uncomfortable because it allows you to move only the top windows, but I think I can survive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long "Super" button pressure revealed a graphical list of the avaialable shortcuts, and I realized that what in Gnome3 is "Super+M", in my version of Unity is "Super+W".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your GNOME version it might differ from one version to another.

According to this page: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts

On version prior to 3.9 you can use the Super or F1 keys, for later versions try using Super or Super+S.

From a personal point of view: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME3 and the Super (Windows) key works just fine.

Comment: Sincerely I don't remember the version I was using, but since Fedora 18 "Super+M" was producing a screen similar to the one in the image I posted. I'm using Unity now, I undestand Gnome could work well in Ubuntu but I have a pre-installed system with Unity and I want to give it a shot. With a long pressure of Super button it appeared a list of all the shortcuts, I saw that in Unity "Super+W" corresponds to Gnome3 "Super+M".

Comment: Sorry, I misread your request, I think you can find what you're looking for in the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts