# Clicking on nautilus opens new window rather than opened ones

Tags: nautilus, 14.04

Whenever I click on Nauitlus (Home) icon

[image] with one opened window, it always opens new rather than showing me opened ones. Is there any tweak for this?

Comment: It's a bug, and its reported:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647

Comment: how it will sovled? via update?

Comment: & it only temporarily opens but after sometimes it behaves exactly as expected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you press `shift` key with clicking.
with `shift` key, you can open new window. and with `wheel` scrolling, you can switch opened instances without new window.

I think that it's very easy, and It's a function of **Unity**.

You can see the additional information at [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts).

Comment: Pressing Shift does the exact opposite, and opens a new instance/new window instead of switching to the open one.

Comment: I could not understand it, when you access any folders other than HOME, it'll open new window.

Comment: as you know, preciese and trusty's desktop environment is not same. precise has unity and mate.

Comment: Why was this answer marked as the accepted one if it suggests the exact  opposite of what was asked?

Answer (score 12):

Since shift-clicking did not work for me I searched and found another solution.

Workaround mentioned in the [corresponding bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1170647): Scroll the mouse wheel on the Nautilus icon.