# Open minimized nautilus window and not open home in launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, 14.04

There is some behavior I can't understand in the Unity Desktop.

1. Open nautilus via. clicking in the launcher onto the home-button
2. Navigate to for example the windows-partition in nautilus
3. Minimize nautilus
4. Click on nautilus in the launcher doesn't open the nautilus with windows-partition, instead it opens a new window with the home folder.

Is there a workaround for this strange behavior?

Regards,
Arthur

Comment: Can you please redescribe your step 2 above? Maybe with picture. Your steps 1, 3 and 4 can be understood, but not step 2.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking on nautilus opens new window rather than opened ones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457459/clicking-on-nautilus-opens-new-window-rather-than-opened-ones)

Answer (score 1):

This has been [confirmed to be a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647) on nautilus. You may add yourself to this bug as it affects you(you will need a launchpad account to do this).

The easiest workaround for this is to hover over to the nautilus icon on the launcher using your mouse pointer and scroll using the middle button if you are using a mouse. If not, you can use the touchpad's scrolling feature, i.e., either two-finger scrolling or edge scrolling or whatever you use to scroll using your touchpad.

[(Source)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647/comments/32)

**Note:** This feature of bringing an already open window to the front works with all applications on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The workaround doesn't work.
When I left-click on the nautilus launcher in the list there are only my bookmarks and at the bottom "Files", altough I have currently openend my windows-partition in nautilus.
Selecting files opens up a new nautilus window with my home folder.

Comment: @8200: You don't need to left-click, you just need to scroll.

Comment: it's not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what I did,

1) Unlock "Files" icon from panel.

2) Goto DASH

3) type in Files and Launch it.

Now if you would minimize and then click on the Nautilus, it behaves the way we want it to. :D

Comment: It's true but But the problem is "1. Open nautilus via. clicking in the **launcher** ..."

Comment: I cannot see your comment.

Comment: you can find that in body of question...

Answer (score 0):

When you open Nautilus window it open Nautilus file manager and when you click on every windows-partition it mount new window under devices an appear in mounted partition in launcher. then use mounted partition icons under files.
see this screen shot below:

[image]

After you click on windows-partition you will see windows-partition on launcher is highlighted. and if you want to open minimized windows-partition click on highlighted icon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed udisks and stopped having this issue. I don't know if it's an intentional feature of the program, but I certainly appreciate it!

If you want to try it:

```
sudo apt-get install udisks
```

Comment: Apparently they don't want your solution to work because now when you try `sudo apt-get install udisks` you get the error: `E: Package 'udisks' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It looks like Udisks has been entirely replaced by Udisks2 on 16.04.

Comment: after some digging last night I sort of learned that :)

Answer (score 0):

1. unlock files from launcher
2. open terminal and write

   ```
   sudo gedit '/usr/share/applications/Home.desktop'
   ```
3. create New Launcher Files

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Home
   Comment=Open Home
   Exec=nautilus
   Icon=folder-home
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Application;System;
   ```
4. save and close
5. go to dash and search for Home
6. drag and drop it to launcher 'now it replaced the last files but
   if you open new window it will do the same as nautilus'
7. trick here is to reopen files and lock to launcher again
8. unlock files from launcher
9. now home will replace the nautilus and Files will only seen if you
   open any file

Comment: Editing your original launcher; bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too. On my system I found that installing unity-tweak-tool and clicking on "reset to default" in the launcher menu fixed this problem... Give it a shot!