# Minimized Nautilus doesn't open

Tags: nautilus, launcher

When I open Nautilus through the launcher bar and minimize it (or change to another window of any other application), I'm not able to come back to Nautilus. If I click on it's icon in the launcher, nothing happens. The little triangle that indicates that an application is minimized doesn't show at the launcher next to Nautilus' icon. Its icon also doesn't show in alt+tab. I am only able to come back to it if I minimize the windows that are in front of it (provided that Nautilus itself has not been minimized).

I have reinstalled Nautilus and I have reset Nautilus configurations to default through `unity-tweak-tool`.

I've found out the problem doesn't happen when I open Nautilus through the terminal, but only if it has not been previously locked to the launcher.

This problem affects only Nautilus as far as I have experienced.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 (newly installed) and Nautilus 3.20.3.

Comment: This might be a known bug. For more information and possible workaround, please have a look at this similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463507/open-minimized-nautilus-window-and-not-open-home-in-launcher

Comment: I actually have seen this question, but it's from more than 2 years ago, so I thought there might be better options by now.