# Extract files to new folder in PCManFM

Tags: pcmanfm, file-roller, decompression

When I use the context menu to extract compressed files on PCManFM, I would like it to automatically create a folder and put the extracted files in it, like it used to happen in Nautilus [back when I was able to use it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854037/minimized-nautilus-doesnt-open), instead of putting all the extracted files in the current folder, which can cause a mess. Is there any way?

Comment: Workaround: Create new folder, move zip into it, click "Extract here". Move zip back if necessary.

Comment: You might want to try Nemo. It's a fork of Nautilus with some bugs fixed and older features added back

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice workaround by creating a desktop entry. Create a file in `~/.local/share/applications` named `extract.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Extract to folder
Comment=Extract archive to a folder with the same name
Exec=file-roller -h %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=file-roller
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

Now in PCManFM, right click the archive > `Open With...`

From `Other`, select `Extract to folder`

Once you do this, when you right click any archive of the same type you will see the `Extract to folder option` in the menu.

Notes:

- You will have to repeat the `Open with...` action once for each file type
- You can right click and extract multiple archives in the same time
- The action will appear in the start menu > `Other`. Clicking it will not do any harm
- If you use other archive manager than the default File Roller, you will have to modify the desktop entry `Exec` and `Icon`entries. See details about entries [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)

Comment: Works! I set this as the default app to open with so all i need is to double-click to extract into folder. Very satisfied, thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Somehow the pcmanfm devs say this is a file-roller thing, but the extract here part seems to be hardcoded anyway, so we're stuck with this solution. However; i needed the icon to be "org.gnome.FileRoller" to work for me properly (I looked in the fileroller.desktop entry which one to choose) so maybe you'll need to update if it shows a blank one. YMMV, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create an action in PCmanFM-Qt. I used the script for extracting from the Manjaro Wiki and changed the line:

`Exec=atool --extract-to=%d %f`

to

`Exec=file-roller -h %F`

The first line is to extract here, and the second, extract to folder. You may also want to change the action's name.

From the Manjaro Wiki:

> ## Creating custom actions
>
> Before creating the actions (which are desktop files), first create its directory/folder by copy-pasting the below command in terminal:
>
> `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions`
>
> ### “Extract” custom action
>
> Create and edit the action file (extract.desktop)
> either by using file manager or by issuing these terminal commands one
> at a time (replace juffed with your text editor if it’s different):
>
> `touch ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/extract.desktop`
>
> `juffed ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/extract.desktop`
>
> Paste the below content in extract.desktop:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry] 
> Type=Action 
> Name[en]=Extract
> Icon=package-x-generic
> Profiles=profile-zero;
>
> [X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
> MimeTypes=application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-7z-compressed-tar;application/x-ace;application/x-alz;application/x-ar;application/x-arj;application/x-bzip;application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;application/x-bzip1;application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar;application/x-cabinet;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cd-image;application/x-compress;application/x-compressed-tar;application/x-cpio;application/x-deb;application/x-ear;application/x-ms-dos-executable;application/x-gtar;application/x-gzip;application/x-gzpostscript;application/x-java-archive;application/x-lha;application/x-lhz;application/x-lzip;application/x-lzip-compressed-tar;application/x-lzma;application/x-lzma-compressed-tar;application/x-lzop;application/x-lzop-compressed-tar;application/x-rar;application/x-rar-compressed;application/x-rpm;application/x-rzip;application/x-tar;application/x-tarz;application/x-stuffit;application/x-war;application/x-xz;application/x-xz-compressed-tar;application/x-zip;application/x-zip-compressed;application/x-zoo;application/zip;multipart/x-zip;
> Exec=atool --extract-to=%d %f 
> Name[en]=Default profile
> SelectionCount==1
> ```
>
> This will uncompress the selected archive into the
> current directory. (You may need to change the icon in the above code
> if you don't have oxygen icons.)

https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=PCmanFM-Qt&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop