# How to create multiple profiles in Opera (running Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, opera

I am using Opera for the first time. I want to create multiple profiles (for home / work). I see some instructions for how to do this, but they are all for Windows and all quite old.

Is there an easy way to do it these days? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Workaround: Use two user accounts for home/work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple entry for opera client by using this command

```
opera --user-data-dir=~/"your new user directory"
```

for simplicity you can save alias to `~/.bashrc`.

> alias op1="opera --user-data-dir=~/opera/user1" 
> alias op2="opera --user-data-dir=~/opera/user2"

or you can create new `.desktop` file check my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/695232/464430).

Answer (score 0):

You have your profile in "`~/.config/opera`"

Create new profile by duplicating it - "`~/.config/opera2`"

And launch opera like this

instance1 - "`opera --profile-directory ~/.config/opera2`"

instance2 - "`opera --profile-directory ~/.config/opera`"

Comment: Thank you. I am in `~/.config/` but I don't see any `opera`.

Comment: @user1551817 you need to launch opera, unless it won't appear

Comment: Opera is certainly open. But I'm afraid there is no `opera` in my `~/.config/` folder. Perhaps it's somewhere else?

Comment: @user1551817 I just tested in ubuntu. The config must appear once you open opera in "`$HOME/.opera`" . There's possibility that you are opening opera with sudo, which makes config appear in "`/root/.config/opera`"