# Files behavior with respect to a secondary hard drive

Tags: nautilus

By "Files", I mean the program Files.

I store the vast majority of my documents on a second hard drive. Suppose I have Files opened up to my documents in this hard drive, except the window is buried below some other ones. On the left panel of icons, I can see an arrow indicating that Files is open. However clicking on the Files icon, instead of taking me to my already open Files window, it instead launches a new one opening to my home folder. This means that I either renavigate to my secondary hard drive, or I have to move/minimize various windows to dig out my already opened Files window.

This behavior does not occur when Files is opened up to something on my primary hard drive (where Ubuntu is installed). Here when I click on the Files icon, it brings up the already opened window.

Is this a known bug? A known feature? I've had trouble searching to see if others have asked about this, and I think that's mostly due to the name "Files".

Comment: Yeah that's a known bug and it's frequently asked in here as well as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/457459/clicking-on-nautilus-opens-new-window-rather-than-opened-ones

Comment: You can always try to go to the opened windows with alt+tab. or you can leave a shortcut to the second hard drive in the desktop/dash icons. that way you would open the correctly opened windows if you click this shortcut.

Comment: @Geo: I already have such a shortcut, but I had no idea it would take me to the proper window! I thought it would open up a new one and hence never tried it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Always have a tab open of your home folder and open your secondary drive on a new tab. That way, clicking on the launcher icon will always show you the opened nautilus instead of opening a new instance.