# alt-f2 stops working and other issues when using a mac keyboard on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac

Trying to switch to an apple keyboard on Ubuntu 12.04 brings up a number of issues.  There's lots of old information out there on google, I'm going to post this as the current solution.

[image: apple keyboard]

1) On a regular keyboard, you're used to having alt next to the spacebar, and the silly Windows, "Command ⌘", or "Super" key sits unused between ctrl and alt. But apple puts their ⌘ key right next to the spacebar making the alt key you use all the time harder to thumb.  Trying to fix that with xmodmap and .xinitrc has no effect outside of terminal applications.

2) alt-f2 to run commands doesn't work anymore? That was *actually* broken until 12.02, but should be fixed now.  That stumps you until you realize:

3) that the f* keys across the top by default now do nifty/useless things like changing the volume of the music. There's a "fn" key where the useless "insert" key used to be that you have to hold to get them to do their normal behavior.

4) The naive approach of using Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts / System has the "Show the run command prompt" Disabled and *italicized*, and you are unable to enable it

[image: run command disabled]

5) Some instructions on the web tell you to use ccsm, the "CompizConfigSettingsManager" under "Gnome Compatibility" and enable the "Run Dialog" but it stubbornly stays disabled:

[image: ccsm run dialog]

6) The "PrintScr" key at F13 doesn't do anything, with or without the "fn" key.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is surprisingly simple.

1) Under Settings / Keyboard / Layout Settings / Options you can swap around the alt/⌘ keys to your liking. I'm trying this option, which swaps Alt and ⌘ just on the left side of the keyboard. But the other option "Control is mapped to Alt keys, Alt is mapped to Win keys" also works, while removing the stupid "⌘" key entirely.

[image]

2) The alt-f2 key [was already there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/28087#28087), just hidden behind needing to hold down "fn". You can [change that behavior](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) to what you really want by

```
$ echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

and to make that permanent

```
$ echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

3) You can set up the "PrintScr" stuff yourself in this settings dialog. Use the f13 key and the settings will change it from "Print" to "Tools". Here's a picture of half of the settings having been changed.

[image]