# Spectacle app alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, windows, software-center

On Mac I have been using the [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) app for moving and resizing windows with simple, customizable keyboard shortcuts. It's very cool.

What similar application can I use for Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the Ubuntu documentation for the keyboard shortcuts?  Many of the behavious I saw on your link are already built into Ubuntu

Answer (score 22):

**This answer assumes you're using Unity as your Desktop Environment.**

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts) answer:

#### Window Placement

If you cycle through the same key Unity will cycle through different placement widths, so experiment by hitting the numkey multiple times, for example Ctrl-Alt-numpad 5 5 5:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> - Place window in top left corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> - Place window in top half of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> - Place window in top right corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> - Center/Maximize the window in the middle of the screen. In 12.04 this toggles between maximize and restore state
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> - Place window in the bottom left corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> - Place window in the bottom half of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> - Place window in the bottom right corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> - Minimize the current window (Ubuntu 12.04.1).

Comment: Fanstastic. Don't know how I missed this. I came to Ubuntu from OS X too where I used a great app called Divvy, similar to spectacle. The best substitute I found with Unity was assigning keyboard shortcuts to Compiz Grid actions. This is much better just by dint of being built in.

Answer (score 9):

For a spectacle-like experience on vanilla Ubuntu (zesty tested):

- Move window to left: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- Move window to right: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- Maximize window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
- Minimize window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

On Kubuntu you need to configure the system, go to: `System Settings` - `Shortcut` - `Global Shortcuts` - `Kwin`:

- Maximaze Window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- Quick tile window to the bottom: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
- Quick tile window to the left:<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- Quick tile window to the right: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- Quick tile window to the top: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: is there any magic needed to make this work on artful ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

There are more answers here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74/tiling-window-manager-functionality-for-normal-linux-desktop-environments
 . They have the advantage of **not being dependent on a particular desktop environment, window manager or even distribution**.

From that answer, my favorite is [Quicktile](https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile), which is very easy to run without even root permission. Plus it works with several screens and is versatile.

From that answer, I quickly tested X-Tile. It is IMHO more complicated and a quick test shows that it operates only on first screen of a multi-screen setup.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Ubuntu comes with premade shortcuts for resizing, moving, etc.:

> Window shortcuts
>
> Alt + Tab
>
> Switch between currently-open windows. Press Alt + Tab and then release Tab (but continue to hold Alt). Press Tab repeatedly to cycle through the list of available windows which appears on the screen. Release the Alt key to switch to the selected window.
>
> Ctrl + Alt + Tab
>
> Switch between currently-open windows in all Workspaces. Press Tab repeatedly to cycle through the list of available windows which appears on the screen. Release the Ctrl and Alt keys to switch to the selected window.
>
> Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Cursor
>
> Lets you quickly switch between your Workspaces.
>
> These might not work on every machine, but are reasonably common:
>
> Alt+F7
>
> Moves the current window (can be moved with mouse or leopard).
>
> Alt+F8
>
> Resizes current window (again, can be moved with mouse or leopard).
>
> Alt+F9
>
> Minimises current window.
>
> Alt+F10
>
> Maximises current window.
>
> Alt+Spaaaaaace
>
> Brings up window menu with with 'Always on Top' and 'Minimise' and 'Maximise' and above commands.
>
> These might change depending on the application you're using, but work for most common applications:
>
> Alt+F5
>
> Returns window to 'normal' or previous size.
>
> Alt+F4
>
> Closes window.