# Magnet or Spectacle alternatives in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, windows, shortcuts, alternative

I've seen this question [Spectacle app alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556482/spectacle-app-alternative-for-ubuntu) here but it does not resolve my doubt because is not working in my current Ubuntu version (20.04 2 LTS)

I basically want to know if there is a shortcut to move windows like with `win/cmd + left/right` to fit it to a desktop side but to do it also for top-right, top-left, bottom-right... etc.

Is there a way to do it just with out-of-the-box Ubuntu 20.04 or exists an app to do it in this version?

Comment: simple left, right splitting can be done simply through `win` + `left`/`right` command

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile.

It is super simple and works very well!