# Display again the first screen after installation 14.04LTS

Tags: system-installation, shortcut-keys, screen

After installing Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I was greeted with a screen that I was afraid I would never see again after closing it, so  I took a picture of it with a camera:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts, first screen after installation of Ubuntu 14.04LTS]

The question is:  How can I display this screen again? (the question is not about finding information about the shortcuts).

EDIT: I emphasize that the question is not what the shortcuts are. What if I want to give my computer to someone else and I want her to be greeted by Ubuntu as if it were the first time?  Of course, since it is so easy to call this screen (according to the answer already posted), then I don't see a point in wanting to have it at the first startup; but still, the question is to get this screen, not the shortcuts.

Comment: Note: this question is [totally about shortcuts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts/28087?s=1|0.0000#28087)...  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try holding down the Super or windows key:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/windows-key.html