# unable to maximize window after snap

Tags: unity, window

When I use the ctr+super+left to maximize a window to half the screen size, then try to maximize it to the full screen, it disappears off the screen.  Any ideas why?

Comment: try look for this post and answer (more then 470 points) [Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Please include your version of Ubuntu.  You might also check displays under settings, to see if you have a second hidden display device.

Comment: @CharlesGreen i am using v15 and have no hidden displays.

Comment: @frankastin Is the problem limited to any particular program, and is the window moving to another workspace?