# Maximize current window to the **top/bottom**?

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I know these shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> - Maximize current window to the left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> - Maximize current window to the right

Sometimes I look at files containing long lines. I would like top have one window at the top and one window at the bottom.

How can I get this working with shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a full-size keyboard:

- Ctrl-Alt-Numpad 8 - Place window in top half of screen.
- Ctrl-Alt-Numpad 2 - Place window in the bottom half of the screen.

Reference: [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

If you're on a laptop, you may need to change the key bindings as you obviously won't have a number pad.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. I am lucky, I have a laptop with numpad :-)

Comment: Is there anyway to re-map those shortcuts?  The new Gnome settings in 17.10 do not offer any keypad shortcuts.