# Ctrl+N shortcut key doesn't work properly

Tags: shortcut-keys, navigation

I use ctrl+N for opening the current directory on windows but on Ubuntu 15.10 it just opens the home directory instead of the current working directory.
 [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) is the list of supported shortcut keys on different OSes and ctrl+n is on the Navigation part and the first one there.

Comment: Sorry but for your problem only nautilus is responsible not the os.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 reached end-of life on July 28, 2016 - I suggest you update to a supported version

Comment: @KuntalMajumder ok, but I'm not looking for the one who is responsible for this. Nautilus or Os it self doesn't matter; why is it like this?

Comment: for your question why this happens : this happens because every  time you press Ctrl + N , a new instance of nautilus is launched, simillar to clicking on the nautilus icon on the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this for ubuntu:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)
The shortcuts of your list are related to KDE, etc.

[Or this lengthy list on askubuntu itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer and I know all these shortcut keys you mentioned exist but ok, now what? still ctrl+n that is for opening current directory isn't working.

Comment: As @KuntalMajumder pointed out. It is related to your "file browser". Usually nautilus. In my case it is caja. How about setting up your own shortcut for your file browser? alt+F2 caja works for me...