# Ubuntu useful shortcuts as print

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04

My work computer is Ubuntu desktop, but I am most familiar with Windows. Because of this I dont know all the smart shortcuts that you can use in Ubuntu.

Example: I know there is a shortcut for terminal start (Something with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), but I can remember it.

Is there any **PDF** **that I can** **print** (and put up on my wall) with a list of shortcuts for Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: HOLD the windows key on an empty desktop.

Comment: Oh: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts

Comment: May be outdated, but most of them will still be functioning: [PDF](http://clusterbleep.net/files/Ubuntu_11.04_Unity_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)

Comment: If necessary you can make a PDF out of this: [KeyboardShortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)

Comment: Make a PDF of that^