# Ubuntu 16.04 – get stuck in full screen

Tags: 16.04

I’m using a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04, on an LG laptop which is quite old, which happens to get “stucked” in full screen mode when running programs ( for example -VNC Viewer, imageViewer ).

PC is not FROZEN since mouse moves OK but I can’t get out from full screen mode- which ends with hard shutdown.

1. Any known reasons for that ?
2. Is there any key combination as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> in Ms-Windows for such situations ?

Comment: Did you try the escape key?

Comment: In VNC Viewer, did you try hitting <F8> to get the toolbar and disabling fullscreen mode there?

Comment: You might want to have a look here: [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts) <Alt>+<F4> to close a window and <Alt>+<Tab> to switch between windows may help you.

Comment: I tried every key on keyboard

Comment: @dessert I even pressed on X at VNC's tab to close connection with no luck.

Comment: It seems to me that when I do vncviewer -fullscreen that no keyboard input has any effect. My current solution is to login & kill the vncserver :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat well it is one way- hopes that there is less aggressive way

Comment: Even though the mouse pointer can be moved, the methods in various answers to [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) apply to this situation. See also [How to fix non-responsive Ubuntu system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39846/how-to-fix-non-responsive-ubuntu-system)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue. I entered ctrl+alt+f2 which took me to the logger page and then i hit ctrl+alt+del and all of a sudden my laptop restarted.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This section is for answers. What you posted does not answer the OP's question. Please consider deleting this answer and adding a comment instead.  Thank you